# Find and count matching cell elements

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a cell like

```
A= {[7,7]; [7,4,7]; [7,7]; [7,7]; [4,5]};
```

I want to count the number of `[7,7]` elements.

How can I do this in MATLAB without using a loop?
Thanks.

Comment: Use the above duplicate, then go one step further and just sum the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cellfun` with `isequal`

```
sum(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, [7 7]), A))
ans =
     3
```